# How to clear and redraw contents of a UIView (present inside a view controller) with swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiview

I've a `UIView` inside a `View Controller` in which I'm drawing few lines as required by my app. After a certain point of time, I want some of those lines to disappear and a few other to appear in the same view. Approach I'm using as of now is that I'm clearing the `UIView` and redrawing all the lines I want to draw in the updated view.

Can somebody tell me what's the right way to go about it? I've gone through various questions that sound similar but it hasn't helped much. Till now I've tried things like:-

```
outletView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

and

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
context?.clear(outletView.frame)
```

None of these seem to make any difference.

If I call `viewDidLoad()` again since all the lines are updated now. New lines to be drawn come up but the ones that were supposed to disappear don't go away. Variables for lines are updated correctly since other logic I have which checks line variable's values is working fine after the update is supposed to happen. Only problem is with the redraw part. In fact, if I understand this correctly, problem is only with cleaning the old uiview contents. If cleaning happens properly, redraw with `viewDidLoad` will show correct lines drawn.

P.S. I know that calling `viewDidLoad()` explicitly isn't a good practice. Hope to find a solution to this problem without having to call viewDidLoad again.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you to call viewDidLoad explicitly. Are you encountering any problems calling setNeedsDisplay()?

Comment: Yes I agree, I don't wish to use viewDidLoad explicitly either.
Using setNeedsDisplay, it doesn't do anything. The point at which I want the lines to be switched, I am adding this code: outletView.setNeedsDisplay()
but it's not redrawing UIView at all. 
After reading Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay), my understanding is that it only marks bounds rectangle to be redrawn but doesn't really redraw itself. May be that's why I don't see any redraw happening with it?

Comment: I guess you are overriding in the view you want to draw on, drawRect: and perform drawing in that method right?

Comment: Nope. I'm not overriding it. Can you please explain briefly what your suggestion is? I can give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Calling setNeedsDisplay() on your view notifies the system that your view’s contents need to be redrawn. setNeedsDisplay() cause drawRect: to be called on the receiver, that's why you should override that method and perform drawing within it. With this option you probably need to have a property on your view for its state to track where the lines need to be drawn as you want to draw the lines in two different ways. The second option instead is as @Ocunidee suggested is to draw using CAShapeLayer in layoutSubviews. With the former approach the context is cleared before drawing again.

Comment: Thanks for your help ubiAle. I went with @Ocunidee suggestion from his comment below and used removeFromSuperLayer. It works fine for me. Anyway, thanks for your explanation. It helped me better understand how setNeedsDisplay works in iOS.

Comment: rather than call viewDIdLoad again, you should put any code you wish to call periodically in its own function, and call that from viewDidLoad. and then from where you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you could draw your lines in different layers of the view, delete the layer containing the lines that need to disappear and create a new layer for the new lines. You can draw in `layoutSubviews()` and use `self.setNeedsLayout()` when you need to update the view.

remove:

```
guard let sublayers = yourView.layer.sublayers else { return }
        for layer in sublayers {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
```

add:

```
let linesPath = UIBezierPath()
let linesLayer = CAShapeLayer()
linesPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
linesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100)
lineLayer.path = linesPath.cgPath
linesLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
linesLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black
yourView.layer.addSublayer(linesLayer)
```

Comment: I went with your suggestion and removing the layer using removeFromSuperLayer works for my use case. Thanks a lot for your help Ocunidee. :)

Comment: It was a pleasure ;)